# When are `If`, `Piecewise`, `Switch`, and `Which` interchangeable and when are they not?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, conditional

Experimenting with [joint dependent distributions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41000/57) via the `TransformedDistribution` function, I used the following to derive a distribution where the second variate is distributed dependent on the value of the first variate (very simplified & contrived example follows).

```
distA = TransformedDistribution[{b, 
   If[b == 1, d1, d2]}, {b \[Distributed] 
    DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 2}],
   d1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1, 2}],
   d2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{2, 3}]}]


distB = TransformedDistribution[{b, 
   Piecewise[{{d1, b == 1}, {d2, b == 2}}]}, {b \[Distributed] 
    DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 2}],
   d1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1, 2}],
   d2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{2, 3}]}]

distC = TransformedDistribution[{b, 
   Switch[b, 1, d1, 2, d2]}, {b \[Distributed] 
    DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 2}],
   d1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1, 2}],
   d2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{2, 3}]}]

distD = TransformedDistribution[{b, 
   Which[b == 1, d1, b == 2, d2]}, {b \[Distributed] 
    DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 2}],
   d1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1, 2}],
   d2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{2, 3}]}]
```

The first two behave as I'd expect: `Mean, Var, RandomVariate` all do what they're supposed to. The latter two, while behaving as expected for the *simple* probability functions (e.g. `Mean`), puke on any attempt to sample with `RandomVariate`, with the message

> TransformedDistribution::nnbprm: The valid numeric parameters of distribution TransformedDistribution[{\FormalX]1,Switch[\FormalX]1,1,\FormalX]2,2,\FormalX]3]},\FormalX]1,\FormalX]2,\FormalX]3}\Distributed]ProductDistribution[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1,2}],UniformDistribution[{1,2}],UniformDistribution[{2,3}]]] are expected. Use DistributionParameterAssumptions to obtain the parameter assumptions. >>

I'm a bit puzzled by this, seems the forms in this case should result in equivalent behavior. Any insights?

Comment: Your use of `If`, `Switch` etc. are not equivalent to begin with.  For example, try `Switch[b, 1, d1, _, d2]` if you want something almost equivalent to your `If`.  (It is equivalent on numeric `b`).

Comment: @MichaelE2: Not sure I understand you. Since b can *only* take values 1 or 2, they are logically precisely equivalent.

Comment: I think what @MichaelE2 means is that `Switch` and `Which` should (could) be setup to return a result at all times. In addition to the use of `Blank[]` in `Switch` you could try `Which[test1, ...,test2, ..., True, output if all tests fail]`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch:Yes, I'm aware of the *optional* use of a fall-through pattern. Nonetheless, such a pattern is unneeded when the test value can only assume "valid" values. In the example with switch, it *is* always falling through, and *that's* what I'd like clarification on: it's as if `switch` and `which` never see the evaluated form of the test value.

Comment: I guess I mean that it seems *Mathematica* does not analyze the distributions, so you might have to use code that is equivalent or close enough, if you wish to use different conditional constructs.  Perhaps the problem is related to this: `Simplify[
 Switch[b, 1, d1, 2, d2] == If[b == 1, d1, d2],
 b == 1 || b == 2
 ]` does not return `True`.  (It does return `True` under the assumption `b == 1`, or `b == 2`, but not their disjunction.)

Comment: @MichaelE2: Yep, I've no real issue with using if/piecewise (I'm glad this can be done, used to return an 'unimplemented' error). But I am curious where else this apparent difference in behavior might be a gotcha, and *why* it's different. Thanks much for your replies!

Comment: The same happens in this simpler example: `distC = TransformedDistribution[Switch[b, 1, 2, 2, 3], b \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 2}]]; RandomVariate@distC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree, all the forms *should* result in the same behaviour. That the `Switch`/`Which` forms fail for `RandomVariate` I regard as a bug.

The whole point of `If`,`Which` and `Switch` possessing this dual nature of being both control-flow conditionals *and* potentially functions is that they can be treated like the latter in cases like this. In other words, the purpose of these constructs remaining unevaluated (when not falling through to a default value) is that they can then assume functional status ready for subsequent symbolic manipulation.

What I suspect is happening here is that `RandomVariate`/`TransformedDistribution`'s error-handling has been over-aggressive in rejecting a `Which`/`Switch` as not being *"valid numeric parameters"*. After all they were  happy enough to accept `If` as a function in this way while `Mean` and `Variance` were happy enough to accept `Which`/`Switch` as "functions".

One (hacky?) way around situations like this is to hit the conditioned expression with `PiecewiseExpand`.

```
distD = TransformedDistribution[{b, 
    Which[b == 1, d1, b == 2, d2] // 
     PiecewiseExpand}, {b \[Distributed] 
     DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 2}], 
    d1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1, 2}], 
    d2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{2, 3}]}];

Through[{Mean, Variance, RandomVariate}[distD]]

(* {{3/2, 2}, {1/4, 1/3}, {2, 2.03136}} *)
```

`PiecewiseExpand` does two things when applied to these imperative conditionals: 1) it converts it into a `Piecewise` expression that downstream functions at least recognise as a function 2) It applies a range of simplifications including logical ones on its conditions.

It is tempting therefore to view `PiecewiseExpand` as an all-purpose tool for instilling robustness as in this example but this is a less than ideal assumption and usage IMO (although the best we have ATM). `PiecewiseExpand` by name and nature has as its prime function performing simplifications on a `Piecewise` function most obviously (but not exclusively) on the logic in the conditional expressions.

Its role on the control-flow conditionals however, includes, in addition, converting it into a `Piecewise` function which may or may not require also hitting it with a rich and extensive set of (logical) transformations. In other words, sometimes we may only want a "`ToPiecewise`" type of action instead of a following, more expensive `PiecewiseExpand` action. In fact, this example is one such case. The fact that it succeeds is not due to any logical deduction that the value of b is restricted to either 1 or 2 somehow making `Switch` and `Which`'s conditions precisely exhaust but rather, it succeeds because of a conversion into a `Piecewise` function from which such a deduction happens automatically when hit by subsequent functions.

For example restricting b to 1 by specifying `DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 1}]`

```
TransformedDistribution[{b, Switch[b, 1, d1, 2, d2]} // 
  PiecewiseExpand, {b \[Distributed] 
   DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 1}], 
  d1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1, 2}], 
  d2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{2, 3}]}]
```

[image]

does *not* entail the expression immediately collapsing to

[image]

Hence in relation to the comments the failure is not due to not having default values in `Which`/`Switch` (this absence is necessary for both constructs to not evaluate in order to be construed as functions) nor is it due to the output of

```
Simplify[Switch[b, 1, d1, 2, d2] == If[b == 1, d1, d2],  b == 1 || b == 2]
```

not returning `True` (although perhaps this should given `Simplify`'s mandate, again alluding to the *WL* unfortunately not automatically recognising these conditionals as functions).

This previous test does however, give us an opportunity to see where `PiecewiseExpand`'s logical simplifications *can* produce this type of logical deduction.

```
PiecewiseExpand[Switch[b, 1, d1, 2, d2] == If[b == 1, d1, d2], 
 b == 1 || b == 2]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Nice analysis of a question I'd forgotten. +1 and the check.

Comment: Thanks. Always wonder about long-standing questions emerging from a different epoch and whether or inputs/outputs are sufficiently similar to afford a meaningful answer. I found the question helpful in the hunt for some good examples to sharpen-up [a recent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/256606/2249).